# EditText cannot delete manually in Android java

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

I've been confused why my EditText can't delete my text manually.When I tried to scan the image that converts to text and display the text to editText or `OCR` sometimes I have this bugs, sometimes only 3 numbers will type instead of 23, and sometimes it runs smoothly, why did this happen? I have sample image below which can't delete the whole text displayed on EdiText manually, can anyone help me with this issue? I can't find the error yet since it just rarely appears, thanks in advance.

[image]

**Java file**

```
 private int prevCount = 0;

 // to have space after 4 number
 private boolean isAtSpaceDelimiter(int currCount) {
    return currCount == 4 ||currCount == 9 || currCount == 14 || currCount == 19;
}

//declared on onCreate()
scannedCardNumber(edt_card_number_inputted,til_card_number_inputted);

public void scannedCardNumber(EditText card_number , TextInputLayout tilCard){
    card_number.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String cardNumber = card_number.getText().toString();
            if(s.toString().length() != 23){
                tilCard.setError(required_field);
            }
            else if(!cardNumber.matches("[0-9 ]+")) {
                tilCard.setError("Invalid Format");
            }
            else{
                tilCard.setError(null);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String field = editable.toString();
            int currCount = field.length();

            if (shouldIncrementOrDecrement(currCount, true)){
                appendOrStrip(field, true);
            } else if (shouldIncrementOrDecrement(currCount, false)) {
                appendOrStrip(field, false);
            }
            prevCount = card_number.getText().toString().length();
        }
    });
}


private void appendOrStrip(String field, boolean shouldAppend) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(field);
    if (shouldAppend) {
        sb.append(" ");
    } else {
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    edt_card_number_inputted.setText(sb.toString());
    edt_card_number_inputted.setSelection(sb.length());
}

private boolean shouldIncrementOrDecrement(int currCount, boolean shouldIncrement) {
    if (shouldIncrement) {
        return prevCount <= currCount && isAtSpaceDelimiter(currCount);
    } else {
        return prevCount > currCount && isAtSpaceDelimiter(currCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem from what you mentioned above. Can you please add some more details like expected behaviour, current behaviour etc. It will make it clearer to understand.

Comment: @Ankur The current behavior is that I cant delete the text in editText and sometimes only it only 3 characters will type in editText

Comment: I see. In what condition/event you are calling `scannedCardNumber` method?

Comment: @Ankur Yes, but the error it just rarely appears do you know the problem?

Comment: Can not say for sure yet, but I see few problems. Like you are adding `addTextChangedListener`. So if you call this method more than one time, `scannedCardNumber` it will add multiple text change listeners which will cause problems. I am also curious about this line `sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1)`

Comment: i guess you always set the text in after text change. put breakpoints over there